# Recognize the site root uri

Tags: wordpress

I need to add button to the WordPress admin panel, only on the site's homepage. How do I create condition for it?

I tried `is_home()` or `is_front_page()`. Doesn't work

How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

- `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` are for the frontend not for the admin panel.
- you can use `$screen = get_current_screen()` to get unique screen id `$screen->id`. please check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen